# When text is entered correctly, image rolls over?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am designing a language learning site.  I want to have it when someone enters text into the text box it starts to roll over certain images.  Take a look at my sample below

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/hiraganaquiz2.jpg/

So, when the user enters "na" the first symbol highlights as you see in my sample.  When he enters "ma" the second symbol should highlight/rollover.  I want all the symbols to stay rolled over while the correct text is entered. so if the user types "nama" the first two symbols should be rolled over to show they got it correct and once the last correct text is entered all three will be rolled over. Can this by done?  Thank you so much!

Comment: exact duplicate of [When user enters correct text, an image rollovers/changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452000/when-user-enters-correct-text-an-image-rollovers-changes) (which has more discussion and an accepted answer) -- please don't double-post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it largely depends on the technology you're using. If you support AJAX you could probably accomplish this using flags of some sort that hide the "unselected" image and replace it with the "selected" one.

I found this forum post. It seems to be similar to your question. I hope it helps:
http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/101640/multiple-mouseover-events