# When user enters correct text, an image rollovers/changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am designing a language learning site. I want to have it when someone enters text into the text box it starts to roll over certain images. Take a look at my sample below

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/hiraganaquiz2.jpg/

So, when the user enters "na" the first symbol highlights as you see in my sample. When he enters "ma" the second symbol should highlight/rollover. I want all the symbols to stay rolled over while the correct text is entered. so if the user types "nama" the first two symbols should be rolled over to show they got it correct and once the last correct text is entered all three will be rolled over.

Can this by done? I will accept advanced and simple methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text = ['na', 'ma', 'ba'];

    $("#elemID").on('keyup', function() {
        var typed = this.value;
        $.each(text, function(index, item) {
            if (typed.indexOf(item)!=-1) {
                $('li', 'ul').eq(index).find('img').addClass('correct');
            }else{
                $('li', 'ul').eq(index).find('img').removeClass('correct');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PT523/1/)

**EDIT:**

At the top of your page, in the `<head>` section, add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then wrap the code in document.ready, see the edited code above on how to do that ?

Comment: This is great! The only thing i need is instead of it making it green, is replacing/rolling over to a different images for each.  So if they enter in "na" the image will change etc for each entered correctly.  Thanks so much! hope that can be done!

Comment: @AnthonyPinskey - Swapping the images should be pretty straight forward, here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/PT523/3/) to show one way of doing it. If you control the image names, you could also just add a number at the end of the filename, and use the `index` value to get the right image etc. Also, if the answer solves the problem, please accept it ?

Comment: I may have stayed up a little to late... but is there something wrong with where I put the code? It works on jsfiddle but not the site, if you have time let me know: http://japaneselanguagefriend.com/apptest.html Thanks so much again!

Comment: It seems like you need to add jQuery, and wrap the code in `$(document).ready(function() {...code here.....});`. The question was tagged with jQuery, so jQuery was used in the answer?

Comment: I made the changes and it still is not working... :(
http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/apptest.html

Comment: @AnthonyPinskey - see my edited answer, you need to add jQuery, right now the page has an error message saying "$ is not defined" ?

Answer (score 1):

On change of the input box, you could do something like this: (totally untested)

```
var parts = ["na", "ma", "blah"];
var start = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  var currentPart = parts[i];
  var $img = $(".images img:nth-child(" + i + ")");
  var end = start + currentPart.length;

  if (str.length >= end && str.slice(start, start + currentPart.length) == currentPart) {
    $img.addClass("highlight");
  } else {
    $img.removeClass("highlight");
  }
  start += currentPart.length;
}
```